# How to validate if server supports TLS 1.0 protocol?

Tags: java, android, ssl

I am writing an android app to connect to application server (SSL based)
Often, i am getting below error (not always)

HttpsUtils(9426): exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection closed by peer

I searched in the forum and found that this error is due to the following reasons.
1. server port address changed
2. TLS 1.0 protocol may not be supported by server

How do I validate if the server works based on TLS 1.0 protocol or not?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't 'connection *reset* by peer'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call SSLSocket.setEnabledProtocols() with only the value "TLSv1", or whatever the equivalent action in HttpsUtils is.